# Opinion on combined strong/weak smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I would like to get some constructive input on smart pointers.

The C++11 standard defines `unique_ptr` and `weak_ptr` such that you can model data dependencies as DAGs with "weak" edges that do not cause dependency cycles.
Thus, the distinction between strong and weak pointers is modelled on the type level.

What about a smart pointer that decides ownership at runtime through a state flag.

We have a smart pointer in our library that does so and has the main advantage that you can point to objects either on the heap or on the stack.

```
MyClass myObj;
my_ptr<MyClass> ptr(&myObj, Slave());
my_ptr<MyClass> ptr2(new MyClass(), Master());
```

What other advantages and disadvantages do you see?
I have not been able to find such a smart pointer in any library so far, so: Are we the first to see the need for this feature or is it a dumb/dangerous idea?

Thanks for all your input!

**Edit**

Apparently, I have not made myself clear enough.
There can be only one master and an arbitrary number of slaves.
In this way, the scheme I propose differs from weak/strong pointers since it is much simpler.

The `my_ptr` class only stores a pointer and the state:

```
template <typename T>
class my_ptr
{
    enum PtrState { MASTER, SLAVE } };

    T * ptr;
    PtrState state;

    my_ptr() : ptr(), state(MASTER) {}
    // ...
    ~my_ptr() { if (state == MASTER) delete ptr; }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Weak pointers need the call to `lock()` to be able to get to the object, but strong pointers do not. How do you solve that difference? Do you use `lock()` always and do nothing in the case of a Master?

Comment: @rodrigo: Maybe I have overlooked this, but where would I need `lock()`, also see my edit for some possible clarification.

Comment: But then, what is the point of a `slave` pointer. It is just an ordinary pointer wrapped into a `my_ptr`, without anything new. If the master gets destroyed, then all the slaves are left dangling... And that's precisely what weak pointers are supposed to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

`shared_ptr` lets you write a custom deleter:

```
struct DontDelete { template<class T> void operator()(T*) {} };

MyClass myObj;
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr(&myObj, DontDelete());
```

The feature is also useful in many other cases, e.g. `shared_ptr<FILE>` can close the file with `fclose`:

```
FILE *f = fopen(...);
// throw if f couldn't open
std::shared_ptr<FILE> file(f, fclose);
// deletes f automatically
```

It's more flexible than `your_ptr`.

Comment: Isn't that a completely orthogonal behaviour to what Manuel describes? I.e. the posibility of adding a custom deleter has absolutely nothing to do with the ability do clearly distinguish master and slave pointers? Or is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @LiKao: my understanding is that the OP misunderstands what weak_ptr is. I'm quite sure that his `Slave()` pointer acts as a plain-old pointer, not as a weak-pointer. Otherwise I can't see how the code in question could work.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yes, apparently I misunderstood `weak_ptr`, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Agreed. I also do not see the sense of the `my_ptr` object being wrapped on the stack. There most likely is another grave misunderstanding somewhere, but I do not think the possibilities for custom deleters is that misunderstanding.

Comment: @LiKao: See my edit for some possible clarification. Maybe I have not made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

One possible downside of your scheme is that *any* `my_ptr` operation could throw, unless you can be sure the pointer you're currently working with is a *Master* one.

I guess you could explicitly promote your working pointer to *Master* status everywhere you need to control lifetime, but without the type system giving you any help here, I expect lots of functions will need to do this explicit promotion just in case.  Particularly in multi-threaded code, note that any dereference of a non-*Master* pointer can potentially fail.

Presumably you know statically when you create a pointer whether it's a *Master* or a *Slave*, and it seems like you often also need to know this when you use it.  So, you're discarding this type information and then re-constructing it ... why?